# Label Name consistency across two objects

Tags: apex, custom-object, label

I have a scenario where on one object, the user enters the SLA for each task(input field) and based on what they enter, I need to create a new record in other custom object. I need to map the label of the SLA input field to a picklist(task name) when I create the new record. . Right now in my trigger, I am taking the API Name of the SLA field and getting the label from the schema of that object, and mapping it to the picklist on the other object.

My question is that:

if the user changes the label of the SLA input field to something that doesn't match to the picklist field on the other object, how do I manage it? Is this manual training point for the client, to change the names consistently across two objects? or can this be done automatically through code?